# Can i access iOS mail app data?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, email, ios5

Is there a way using which i can access attachments downloaded though the iOS Mail app? I need to access photos or other documents in my app.

Comment: what's up with all the downvotes? Could some downvoters explain so we can make chunky feel welcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No You cannot access the Mail App Data in any way. It is against the Privacy concerns of the iOS device user. However, the images in the user's iPhone Gallery can be accessed and used in the app according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you register your app to handle various file types, then you could select open with yourapp from within the mail application. So you could send a file from the mail application to your app. For more information see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

Answer (score 0):

No, You are not authorized to take any device data without user interaction that too limited access. You can create your customized mailing data with you have sent mails.